# Azure ARM Template osprofile dependency

Tags: azure, deployment

I have problem when creating my custom template. I am trying to create VM from vhd as vhd but in deployment it fail with error `osProfile` missing. It is interesting because in other template from internet I see there is no osprofile section and it is deploying without problems.

So I added `osProfile` with `computerName` parameter. But now deployment failing with error there is `adminUsername` and `adminPassword` needed. I don´t understand how is possible that in another script this is not requied and it will create VM without problems.

There is also fact that my template is creating VM using vhd but that other template is creating VM using managed disk. Is this possibly problematic?

My piece of code:

```
"apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'))]",
                    "adminUsername": "",
                    "adminPassword": ""
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'-osDisk')]",
                        "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "image": {
                            "uri": "[parameters('osVhdUri')]"
                        },
                        "vhd": {
                            "uri": "[variables('osDiskVhdName')]"
                        },
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "storageUri": "[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('userDiagStorageAccountName')), '2016-01-01').primaryEndpoints.blob)]"
                    }
                }
```

I know `adminUsername` and `adminPassword` can´t be empty but I don´t want this parameters in creating VM from existing vhd.

Piece of template code from deployment successful:

```
"apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "VirtualMachine"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]",
                "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '_OSdisk')]",
                "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '_Datadisk')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "createOption": "Attach",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', concat(parameters('vmName'), '_OSdisk'))]"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataDisks": [
                        {
                            "lun": 0,
                            "managedDisk": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', concat(parameters('vmName'), '_Datadisk'))]"
                            },
                            "caching": "ReadOnly",
                            "createOption": "Attach"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "storageUri": "[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('diagStorageAccountName')), '2016-01-01').primaryEndpoints.blob)]"
                    }
                }
```

Here is printscreen of failed deployment without osProfile form my template.
[image]

Comment: search the VHD templates here and see if any of these are suitable https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `"createOption": "FromImage"` to `"createOption": "Attach"`. You are trying to create a VM from marketplace image, not from existing VHD.

in this case you can remove osProfile completely

Comment: Thank you, but after I changed it new error appear in deployment: Cannot attach an existing OS disk if the VM is created from a platform or user image.

Comment: are you using a generalized vhd? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-java-manage-vm/issues/10

Comment: no because this vhd is from existing azure VM. I only converted managed os disk from this existing Azure VM to vhd.

Comment: is the vm resource in azure already? delete the vm resource and try again. there are many things that can be wrong, check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e77a1d92-936d-4978-a61a-27743d08e10c/attaching-an-existing-os-disk-to-an-existing-rm-vm-is-not-possible?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows. But you should be using attach. I suggest you close this question and investigate whats going on and come back with a new question. because this one is solved (although you still have a problem, its a different one)

Comment: I got it with your help. So I changed FromImage to Attach as you say, next deleted this part `"name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'-osDisk')]",
                        "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "image": {
                            "uri": "[parameters('osVhdUri')]"
                        },` and last thing was dash (-) It was in another part of code. I removed dash from here `parameters('vmName'),'-osDisk.vhd')]", `

Comment: my pleasure. :)